# Stopping Ribbon from Auto Collapsing in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

In ArcGIS Pro 2.7 how do you stop the ribbon from collapsing every time you click outside of the ribbon?

For example, to edit a polygon I must click the Edit menu option, this opens the ribbon and I can select the selection tool.  Then I can select my polygon but the ribbon collapses. To select an editing tool I have to click Edit again to open the ribbon and select some editing tool.  This results in a lot of extra clicking. I do not see a setting in the Project Options to fix the ribbon.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's this tiny down-arrow at the far right of the ribbon. If it's pointing up, the ribbon will auto-collapse. If it's down, the ribbon will stay open. You can also use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl-F1` to toggle it on and off.

[image]

Many other applications that use a 'ribbon' have the same button in the same place:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Click on this arrow in top right of application

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icon to pin other features (geoprocessing, contents etc.) is actually a pin symbol (example above). I find that much more intuitive and would be consistent with other Arc pin functions - but not with other software. No winning for devs sometimes.